# Passing javascript variable to a function I get a null value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Jquery and I did create a variable where I do return a json object. This function waits two parameters, the first one is a source and the second one is a global variable where I hope the function save it. But When I want get the value from the global variable this is empty.

This is my code

```
$(function(){
var selectedSuggestion1 = null;
var selectedSuggestion2 = null;


loadSuggestions(responseObject);

$('#btnShow').click(function(){
    var drp = $('#range1').data('daterangepicker');
    console.log(selectedSuggestion1);
    var params = {};
    params['id'] = selectedSuggestion1.id;
    params['type'] = selectedSuggestion1.type;
    params['startDate'] = drp.starDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    params['endDate'] = drp.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    console.log(params);
});

function loadSuggestions(comparative){
    var arrCustomerSug = new Array();
    $.each(comparative.lsCustomersSug, function(i, e){
        arrCustomerSug.push({
            type: 1,
            value: e.name,
            id: e.id
        });
    });

    var cfgAutoComplete = function(source, variable){
            var jsonResponse = {
                    source: source,
                    select: function(event, ui){
                        variable = ui.item;
                    },
                    search: function(event, ui){},
                    messages:{
                        noResults: '',
                        results: function(){}
                    }
            };
            return jsonResponse;
    }

    $('#inpCustomerSuggestion1').autocomplete(cfgAutoComplete(arrCustomerSug, selectedSuggestion1));
```

Exactly in "cfgAutoComplete" function. I pass the global variable "selectedSuggestion1" to the function and when the select function is active this one must save the value on my variable. But doesn't it.

At the click function I try to get the value but this one comes empty.
And if I put the global variable as is, I get value. But I need that this be dynamic.

Comment: clearly the function passed to `select` isn't being executed. Start there.

Answer (score 0):

In this function call

```
cfgAutoComplete(arrCustomerSug, selectedSuggestion1)
```

`selectedSuggestion1` is a string.  Its value is passed into cfgAutoComplete, not a reference to the global variable.  So, within your function, updating `variable` won't update the global var like you intend.

Quick and dirty fix, pass the name of the global in as a string:

```
cfgAutoComplete(arrCustomerSug, "selectedSuggestion1")
```

and then in cfgAutoComplete, find and update the global variable you want via the `window` object

```
var cfgAutoComplete = function(source, globalName){
        var jsonResponse = {
                source: source,
                select: function(event, ui){
                    window[globalName] = ui.item;
                    ...
```